# How to test for validation error from go-playground/validator?

Tags: unit-testing, validation, go

Let's say I am using [go-playground/validator](https://github.com/go-playground/validator) for validation,

```golang
import (
    "github.com/go-playground/validator"
)

type Query struct {
    ID string `json:"id" validate:"required,uuid4"`
}

var validate := validator.New()

func DoSomething(query Query) error {
    err = r.validate.Struct(query)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // otherwise do something else

    return nil
}
```

and want to test `DoSomething` using [stretchr/testify](https://github.com/stretchr/testify/suite),

```golang
import (
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestDoSomething(t *testing.T) {
    err := DoSomething(Query{})
    assert.Equal(s.T(), SomeError, err)
}
```

*How do I have to set `SomeError` such that the test passes?*

The challenge is that the `error` returned by `validator.Struct(...)` can be either `validator.InvalidValidationError` (error in the validation logic itself) or `validator.ValidationErrors` (validation constaint not satisfied).

We are interested in `validator.ValidationErrors`, therefore we might want to change,

```
func DoSomething(query Query) error {
    err = r.validate.Struct(query)
    if err != nil {
        if err, ok := err.(validator.ValidationErrors); ok {
            return err
        } else {
            // panic 
        }
    }

    // otherwise do something else

    return nil
}
```

However, from the [go-playground/validator tests](https://github.com/go-playground/validator/blob/master/validator_test.go) we see that `validator.ValidationErrors` is a slice of `validator.FieldError`.

**I am searching for a way to test explicitly for validation errors in functions that use [go-playground/validator](https://github.com/go-playground/validator).**

Answer (score 1):

The best I've been able to get to is getting a map back of errors utilizing the Translation function:

```golang
import (
    "github.com/go-playground/locales/en"
    ut "github.com/go-playground/universal-translator"
    "github.com/go-playground/validator"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func TestStructIsValid(t *testing.T) {
    /*
    This section just sets up translators with defaults. You can write your own
    per the specification to get the data the way you want.
    */

    v := validator.New()
    en := en.New()
    uni := ut.New(en, en)
    trans, _ := uni.GetTranslator("en")

    invalidItem := Item{
        CreatedAt:          time.Time{},
        UpdatedAt:          time.Time{},
    }

    err := v.Struct(invalidTemplate)

    assert.NotNil(t, err)
    assert.Error(t, err)

    //Cast to Validation Error and validate assumptions

    validationErr := err.(validator.ValidationErrors)

    fieldErrors := validationErr.Translate(trans)

    assert.Len(t, fieldErrors, 3)

    //Check to see if the map contains a key of Template.Name
    assert.Len(t, fieldErrors, 3)
    require.Contains(t, fieldErrors, "Template.Name")

    if nameField, ok := fieldErrors["Template.Name"]; ok {
        //Let's evaluate the error and make sure it's what we expect
        assert.Contains(t, nameField, "required")
    }

}
```

I got here from the example for translations:
[Validator Examples: Translation](https://github.com/go-playground/validator/blob/f6584a41c8acc5dfc0b62f7962811f5231c11530/_examples/translations/main.go#L75)

What you get is a `map[string]string` where the key is the struct field name and the value is the *translated* text.